# How to rescale a function?

Tags: sequence-analysis

When we have a function which takes values ​​in [a,b] and which returns values ​​in [c,d], what transformation can we do so that the function takes values ​​in [0,1] and returns values ​​in [0,1] without the curve changing in both cases?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example that doesn't involve something like "function(x) return x;", which is what you're implying.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want a linear transformation (which is what "without the curve changing" sounds like to me), to rescale from range **c..d** to range **0..1** subtract the minimum then divide by the difference, i.e.

$val_t = (val - c) / (d-c)$

The inverse of this can be applied to work the other way, i.e.

$inp_t = val \times (b-a) + a$

For a function $f(x)$, with ranges as you have stated, the full transformation of input and output would be:

$g(x_t) = \frac{f(x_t \times (b-a) + a) - c}{d-c}$

Comment: Very cool response